# Update Manager not loading

Tags: 22.04, vpn, update-manager, freeze, system

The update manager is freezing.It only closes with system monitor. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cuNF.png

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` on the command line? You might get more of an idea on what is failing